# Find the solution to an equation and show graphically that these lie on a circle in the complex number plane

Tags: complex

I need to find the solution to the equation in the picture, and show graphically that these lie on a circle in the complex number plane. How would one go about this?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> and show graphically that these lie on a circle in the complex number
> plane

You could use the absolute value of one of the solution as the radius

```
eq = z^5 == -3 + 3*I
sol = z /. Solve[eq, z]  
radius = Abs[sol[[1]]];
p1 = ComplexListPlot[sol, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Graphics[{LightOrange, Disk[{0, 0}, radius]}, Axes -> True];
Show[p2, p1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Or `BoundingRegion`.

```
pts = NSolveValues[z^5 == -3 + 3 I, z];
reg = BoundingRegion[ReIm@pts, "MinDisk"];
ComplexListPlot[pts, 
 Prolog -> {EdgeForm[Red], 
   FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.2], LightBlue]], reg}, 
 PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image]